# Remotely access info path field in SharePoint 2007

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, infopath

I have sharepoint document library which contains infopath files, however I want to write a c# console program to read a field of infopath file, from a client machine, via sharepoint web service.

how do i do that? I am not allowed to deploy any code to sharepoint server.

Answer (score 1):

Couple steps involved.
1. Get the infopath file from the Sharepoint server using webservices. You most likely will use `GetListItems` to find the name/URL of the file and then you can use a webclient class to stream the file.
2. Once you have the file locally (in memory) you can read any infopath using the standard XMLReader class methods.

Shouldn't be terribly complicated but does involve a few different technologies (web services, web client, XML).

Answer (score 1):

One other option would be to promote the field from the form into the SharePoint library (providing it is not a field in a repeating section or a rich text field) and then use the lists web service (http://mysite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx) to find your record and read the promited fields value from the returned results in web services.

Here is a link that will hopefully help you wish the lists.asmx web service (if you need it): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Hope this helps